# Xamarin.Forms call method from another controller

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a MasterDetailPage. In my master page I am calling the OnAppearing method like so:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {

            List<MasterPageItem> menu = new List<MasterPageItem>();

            var myValue = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("token");

            if(myValue == null)
            {
                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Home",
                    TargetType = typeof(HomePage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Search Patients",
                    TargetType = typeof(PatientsPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Search Professionals",
                    TargetType = typeof(ProfessionalsPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Blog",
                    TargetType = typeof(BlogPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Register",
                    TargetType = typeof(RegistrationPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Login",
                    TargetType = typeof(LoginPage)
                });

            }
            else
            {
                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Home",
                    TargetType = typeof(HomePage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Search Patients",
                    TargetType = typeof(PatientsPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Search Professionals",
                    TargetType = typeof(ProfessionalsPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Blog",
                    TargetType = typeof(BlogPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Messages",
                    TargetType = typeof(MailboxPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Account",
                    TargetType = typeof(AccountPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Logout",
                    TargetType = typeof(LoginPage)
                });
            }

            listView.ItemsSource = menu;

        }
```

How ever it only gets called once when I goto the master page for the first time. I am looking for away to refresh my listView when someone logins or logouts.

I have tried the following on my LoginPage

```
protected async void OnLogin(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginClass response = await webService.LoginAsync(Email.Text, Password.Text);

            var myValue = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("token");

            Console.WriteLine(myValue);

            if (response.error != null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", response.error, "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                await SecureStorage.SetAsync("token", response.token);

                MasterPage masterPage = new MasterPage();

                masterPage.createMenu();
            }

        }
```

and created a new method in my master page called createMenu and its being called, but my listView does not get updated and it should be the "token" has been created.

```
public async void createMenu()
        {
            List<MasterPageItem> menu = new List<MasterPageItem>();

            var myValue = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("token");

            if (myValue == null)
            {
                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Home",
                    TargetType = typeof(HomePage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Search Patients",
                    TargetType = typeof(PatientsPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Search Professionals",
                    TargetType = typeof(ProfessionalsPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Blog",
                    TargetType = typeof(BlogPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Register",
                    TargetType = typeof(RegistrationPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Login",
                    TargetType = typeof(LoginPage)
                });

            }
            else
            {
                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Home",
                    TargetType = typeof(HomePage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Search Patients",
                    TargetType = typeof(PatientsPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Search Professionals",
                    TargetType = typeof(ProfessionalsPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Blog",
                    TargetType = typeof(BlogPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Messages",
                    TargetType = typeof(MailboxPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Account",
                    TargetType = typeof(AccountPage)
                });

                menu.Add(new MasterPageItem
                {
                    Title = "Logout",
                    TargetType = typeof(LoginPage)
                });
            }

            listView.ItemsSource = menu;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: if you need to communicate between pages using MessagingCenter is often a good option

Comment: I have seen this in the doc but the only way I’ve seen it used is in the same page...example please?

Comment: there are many existing samples, and there are only two method calls involved.  Using it on two different pages should be no more complex than using it on the same page.

Comment: Found a working example. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if you have found a solution, you could update it in answer when you have time, then others also will know how to solve that when they have the same problem.